# computer not restarting after water drop

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios

Someone spilled water over my desktop.  The water did not go inside the case but it flowed at the back side where I attach  thewires like for the keyboard, USB etc.

Now when I start the computer I can see POST start. the VGA BIOS is displayed followed by a `press F2 for BIOS`.  Next I see a blank screen.

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd> then the computer just hangs there.

What can be the problem?

Comment: By CPU you obviously mean your desktop PC's cabinet. If you had spilt water on a running CPU I'm sure it would have been toast. So, are you *sure* no water entered inside the case? Did you turn off the PC and carefully dry the spilt water before restarting? Did you ensure the cable contacts and ports if wet were completely dry? (Use a cloth and then allow the rest to dry naturally. Don't use a hot blow dryer.)

Comment: The problem?  Let the thing dry out for awhile before.  If the situation still does not improve, its probably time either to consider repairs or to get a new computer.

Comment: yes i mean the cabinet. i din't dry the water before . i wiped the wires connectors later and now they are dry. at the worst what do i need to replace

Comment: Can't say sitting here. Turn it off, wait for a day or more and then retry. If no change, take it to a shop and let them have a look inside.

Comment: @user199768, the connectors are soldered to the motherboard. If there was some short-circuit in that, they probably can't be salvaged. New motherboard time, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ack! You shouldn't have applied power until *after* you dealt with the water.

Comment: i didnt knew if that has gone at back sides. small child did it. it was sprite can not water. i find it now

Comment: I think you're screwed. You can try some of the suggestions here but you should look into a repair shop or a new computer if the computer doesn't work after the suggestions. Also, if your computer is over 5 years old and the repairs will be over $200, get a new system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you spilled water over the CPU (That is one of the chips **inside** the case), then the water most definitively was inside. I suspect you mean you spilled water over the desktop case.

Normally when this happens the first thing you want to do is to **immediately** remove the power from the computer. Unplug it, not just turning it off but remove the power plug from the socket. Then clean up as much moisture as you can and check the inside of the case and the hollow parts of plugs.  Those will need to dry completely.

If it was clean water then leaving it near a radiator for a few days might solve it.

If it was not clean water then you would need to clean it first using clean (distilled) water and then let it dry. Esp if in the case of acids like orange juice. Anyway, you said water, so it should not be that bad.

Next you have two options:

1. Remove the harddisks. Make a backup of those (these contain your data)
2. Or just try it and boot it. Do not be impatient though. Wait long enough until everything is completely dry. Even if it takes a week.

In your case it sounds as if you still have moisture somewhere, conducting electricity and/or shortening things. Which means that either you did not wait long enough, or the water was polluted and left salts or corrosive stuff.

So, wait longer for it to dry. Not hours longer. Days.

Comment: it was the sprite can not water. is that ok

Comment: That is not good. That has sugar in it, which will form a layer once things have dried (as well attract moisture so it might not completely dry).

Comment: what should  i do

Comment: If you have good backups: Take the computer to a shop or some technical skilled friend or family member. If not first remove the hard disk(s) from the case. Everything else is replaceable, even if it might cost money. Data on a harddisk (e.g. wedding pictures, diaries, etc) is not. Then let them fix the problem (which most likely comes down to replacing the motherboard). Reconnect the harddisk only after that is done and it all works again.

Comment: can i replace mother board myself , i can buy the newone , what else can the repair person do. i know the basic skills and i have assebled that pc myself from scracth before. that was quad core ddr2. i think now i will buy 1155 i7

Comment: Not much, from what I can read it is most likely only a motherboard replacement. Which is both easy to do and easy to mess up. (E.g.  forgetting to re-apply fresh thermal paste to the CPU/cooler is easy to forget). I would like to stress the **most likely** part though. From here, behind a browser with just text, I am not going to guarantee anything.

Comment: I tried in the morning and computer has booted but the ps keyboard is not working. i am not sure if the everything has dried or not. beside motherboard if i continue to use is there any chance of other thing getting damaged

Comment: If there is a (mild) short circuit or if there remains slightly corrosive or moist attracting remains (e.g. saugar): Yes. But since it is an old computer the only two question you need to ask yourself are: 1) Do I have good backups?  2) Is the cost of replacing the MB worth the piece of mind, or do you not mind and just replace the system in the case it fails completely. That last is a question only you can answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sprite is acidic (carbonic acid) and contains sugar which won't evaporate. You'll probably need to remove the motherboard, rinse the ports with clean water, and thoroughly dry the motherboard before applying power. There's a good chance the motherboard will need to be replaced.

Do not rinse the hard drives under any circumstances. Pretty much all other components can be rinsed. Do not let water get near any connection that remains attached. For example, if you need to rinse 
near the CPU socket, you must remove the CPU.

You can dry the motherboard with a hair dryer. You'll need to thoroughly dry any trapped spaces where water can hide. Do not let components overheat -- take your time. It will still need at least a day to finish air drying.

This may be something you'd prefer to let a professional do. If you're not comfortable removing the motherboard, you probably shouldn't attempt it.

Comment: Ack. I never even considered people might try to rinse a HDD. Good warning.

Comment: Why exactly is it a bad idea to rinse an HDD but okay for other components? What about an SSD?

Comment: i had LGA 775 mother board with intel Q6600 core 2 quad processor. is 775 mother borad still available

Comment: LGA 755 is old and many shops might not have them in supply. But I found at least a dozen of them in webshops, so yes, they are available.

Comment: If you are trying to clean something sticky on the motherboard. Be sure to use alcohol (or denatured alcohol).

Comment: I tried in the morning and computer has booted but the ps keyboard is not working. i am not sure if the everythin